# How to check if a specific button exists in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I have a button in web page as

```
 <input class="nextbutton" type="submit" name="B1" value="Next 20>>"></input>
```

Now i want to check if this button exists on the page or not using Xpath selectors so that if it exists i can go to next page and retreive information from there.

Comment: You could test a few different things. What's the most differentiating property of this button? its "nextbutton" class? its name? its value? a combination of these?

Comment: I tried using "hxs.select('//input[@class="nextbutton"]')" but it is returning null

Comment: Please provide the sample URL if you can. Check if there are no spaces inside the class attribute

Comment: "http://www.trumed.org/patients-visitors/find-a-doctor". Provide "C" in Provider Last Name Field and it will show u the list of doctors. As the list is going to be long in this case it shows "Next 20" button

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to determine what counts as "this button".  Given the context, I'd suggest looking for an input with a class of 'nextbutton'. You could check for an element with only one class like this in XPath:

```
//input[@class='nextbutton']
```

But that looks for exact matches only. So you could try:

```
//input[contains(@class, 'nextbutton')]
```

Though this will also match "nonextbutton" or "nextbuttonbig". So your final answer will probably be:

```
//input[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' nextbutton ')]
```

In Scrapy, [a Selector will evaluate as true if it matches some nonzero content](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.__nonzero__). So you should be able to write something like:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
input_tag = Selector(text=html_content).xpath("//input[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' nextbutton ')]")
if input_tag: 
    print "Yes, I found a 'next' button on the page."
```

Comment: An alternative to XPath `//input[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' nextbutton ')]` is the equivalent CSS selector (thanks to underlying cssselect) `.css("input.nextbutton")`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.trumed.org/patients-visitors/find-a-doctor loads an `iframe` with `src="http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/"`

```
<iframe border="0" frameborder="0" id="I1" name="I1"
        src="http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/"
        style="width: 920px; height: 600px;" target="I1">
Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.
</iframe>
```

The search form is in this iframe.

Here's a scrapy shell session illustrating this:

```
$ scrapy shell "http://www.trumed.org/patients-visitors/find-a-doctor"
2014-07-10 11:31:05+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
2014-07-10 11:31:07+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.trumed.org/patients-visitors/find-a-doctor> (referer: None)
...

In [1]: response.xpath('//iframe/@src').extract()
Out[1]: [u'http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/']

In [2]: fetch('http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/')
2014-07-10 11:31:34+0200 [default] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/applicationspecific/intropage.asp> from <GET http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/>
2014-07-10 11:31:35+0200 [default] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/applicationspecific/search.asp> from <GET http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/applicationspecific/intropage.asp>
2014-07-10 11:31:36+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/applicationspecific/search.asp> (referer: None)
...

In [3]: from scrapy.http import FormRequest

In [4]: frq = FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'LastName': 'c'})

In [5]: fetch(frq)
2014-07-10 11:32:15+0200 [default] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/applicationspecific/SearchStart.asp> from <POST http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/applicationspecific/search.asp>
2014-07-10 11:32:15+0200 [default] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/applicationspecific/searchresults.asp> from <GET http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/applicationspecific/SearchStart.asp>
2014-07-10 11:32:17+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://verify.tmcmed.org/iDirectory/applicationspecific/searchresults.asp> (referer: None)
...

In [6]: response.css('input.nextbutton')
Out[6]: [<Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::input[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' nextbutton ')]" data=u'<input type="submit" value=" Next 20 &gt'>]

In [7]: response.xpath('//input[@class="nextbutton"]')
Out[7]: [<Selector xpath='//input[@class="nextbutton"]' data=u'<input type="submit" value=" Next 20 &gt'>]

In [8]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [Scrapy Selectors documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) , you can use xpath and element property for check element  Exists or not.

try this!

```
isExists = response.xpath("//input[@class='nextbutton']").extract_first(default='not-found')
if( isExists == 'not-found'):
     # input Not Exists
     pass 
else:
     # input Exists , crawl other page
     pass
```