# Scrapy How to check if certain class exists in a given element

Tags: python, scrapy

```
<li class="a">category1</li>
<li>subcatergory1</li>
<li>subcatergory2</li>
<li class="a">category2</li>
<li>subcatergory1</li>
<li>subcatergory2</li>
```

I'm looping through an `ul` which contains 2 kinds of `li`, one has `a` class and one doesn't. I'm wondering is there an existing method to check if the `a` class exists in a given `li`, rather than extracting class value and compare it manually.

```
for li in ul
    if (li has class:a)
        ....
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You could check for an element with only one class like this in XPath:

```
//li[@class='a']
```

But that looks for exact matches only. So you could try:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'a')]
```

Though this will also match "noa" or "abig". So your final answer will probably be:

```
//li[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' a ')]
```

In Scrapy, a Selector will evaluate as true if it matches some nonzero content. So you should be able to write something like:

```
li_tag = response.xpath("//li[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' a ')]")
if li_tag: 
    print "Yes, I found an 'a' li tag on the page."
```

Main answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24672484/2250391)

Answer (score 0):

li.css('.a') should do it
or
li.xpath('@id').extract()

if you need only class=a elements than
ul.css('li.a') will do it.