# Scrapy scraping content that is visible sometimes but not others

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am scraping some info off of zappos.com, specifically a part of the details page that displays what customers that view the current item have also viewed.

This is one such item listing:
https://www.zappos.com/p/chaco-marshall-tartan-rust/product/8982802/color/725500

The thing is that I discovered that the section that I am scraping appears right away on some items, but on others it will only appear after I have refreshed the page 2 or three times.

I am using scrapy to scrape and splash to render.

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class Scrapys(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sqs"
    start_urls = ["https://www.zappos.com","https://www.zappos.com/marty/men-shoes/CK_XAcABAuICAgEY.zso"]
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                endpoint='render.html',
                args={'wait': 0.5},
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css("div._1Mgpu")
        for link in links:
            url = 'https://www.zappos.com' + link.css("a::attr(href)").extract_first()
            yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse_attr,
                endpoint='render.html',
                args={'wait': 10},
            )


    def parse_attr(self, response):
        alsoviewimg = response.css("div._18jp0 div._3Olkk div.QDcUX div.slider div.slider-frame ul.slider-list li.slider-slide a img").extract()
```

The alsoviewimg is one of the elements that I am pulling from the "Customers Who Viewed this Item Also Viewed" section. I have tested pulling this and other elements, all in the scrapy shell with splash rendering to get the dynamic content, and it pulled the content fine, however in the spider it rarely, if ever, gets any hits.

Is there something I can set so that it loads the page a couple times to get the content? Or something else that I am missing?

Comment: With reloading the page I was able to get more of the element that I am looking for. However, while doing some testing I found selenium worked without having to reload the URL in the program as it found the element right away. I am not sure what the difference is between Splash rendering the page and Selenium rendering but if I could find it it would help me to build a scraper that is faster than using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the element you're looking for exists. If it doesn't, load the page again.

I'd look into why refreshing the page requires multiple attempts, you might be able to solve the problem without this ad-hoc multiple refresh solution.

[Scrapy How to check if certain class exists in a given element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825706/scrapy-how-to-check-if-certain-class-exists-in-a-given-element)

This link explains how to see if a class exists.

Comment: Ahhh didn't even think to reload the page, does scrapy have a specific method for reloading pages? I have been doing some digging as to why it only shows up sometimes and have come up empty so far.

Comment: I haven't really used scrapy myself, but I think you can use scrapy.request() to load a page. Just loop that until you find the element you need. Let me know if it works.

Comment: So I have check to see if the div exists, and if it doesn't using response.request.url to get current url and restart the parse of it. That seems to have done it, however it is much slower now. Gotta find a way to see why it takes multiple loads to get it to show.